# Packaging DLLs with a LabVIEW Toolkit

Tags: dll, installation, labview

I have a set of utility LabVIEW VIs that make calls to a custom DLL written in C++.  I'd like to package the VIs into a LabVIEW toolkit and deploy it via an installer, but am unsure about the standard practices involved in doing this where a custom DLL is involved.  I've looked at VIPM for packaging the VIs, but so far I haven't found a way to generate a package and include the appropriate DLL dependencies.  What is the correct way to go about generating an installer for a LabVIEW Toolkit **and** installing the DLL dependency for said toolkit in the correct location (*where ever that may be*)?

Comment: What are LabVIEW and VIPM version? I never did what you're trying to do, but if you use LV 2010 it's safe to specify the DLL path to the function node, and determine DLL path programatically before

Comment: @CharlesB I'm using LabVIEW 2011, and I'm using the latest Community version of VIPM.  I didn't think about setting the DLL path programmatically. I had already been setting the DLL in this way to switch between Debug and Release versions; this should have occurred to me :P

However, this might still be problematic for an enduser wanting to deploy an app that uses the toolkit -- some of the DLL dependencies are loaded via late binding, so LabVIEW won't know to automatically include them as dependencies when compiling an executable or any other build...

Comment: DLLs dependencies have to be added in package creation. I never created packages with VIPM, so the only thing I can say is RTFM :) I'm sure it's possible as the use case is quite common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLLs immediately known to the system - i.e., the ones entered in the CLFN node - are added automatically.

DLLs which are used indirectly and DLLs which are determined programmatically cannot be auto-included and must be added manually to the Source files section of the respective Build rule.